# Can Apache Flume be used to extract tweets for a certain period of time?

Tags: apache, hadoop, twitter, flume

I want to extract twitter feeds related to a keyword for the months of June and July using Apache Flume. Can this be done in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the `TwitterSource` from [Cloudera](http://files.cloudera.com/samples/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) is just for receiving data at the same time it is generated. I think something similiar occurs with the [Twitter 1% firehose source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#twitter-1-firehose-source-experimental).

Nevertheless, I'm seeing the Twitter API may work with [timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines), thus it is a matter of modifying the [`TwitterSource`](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/flume-sources/src/main/java/com/cloudera/flume/source/TwitterSource.java) source code.